# In the SSMS copy database wizard, how do I access the files in the destination folder (screenshot)?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

[image]

SSMS Specifics:

```
SQL Server Management Studio                    15.0.18206.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        15.0.1567.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         10.0.18362.1
Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.18362.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                10.0.18363
```

I am using the copy database wizard in SSMS and in this step (Screenshot), file formats `.ldf`, `.mdf` and `.ndf` are being stored in E:\ (Destination Folder - Screenshot).

I do not have a E:\ in my system, so is this a mounted drive. If yes, how do I retrieve these files after the copy process is complete?

Further, is there an official documentation for how the copy process is performed?
I have already read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [documetented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15#select-the-transfer-method) that that method uses [attach/detatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15), and drive letter mappings in windows are account-specific, and it's the SQL Server service account doing the file access.  So use the full `\\server\share\folder\file` unc path.

Answer (score 1):

The Copy Database Wizard defaults to the [default paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/view-or-change-the-default-locations-for-data-and-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15) of the Destination SQL Server. The default locations are configured in server properties --> Database Settings of SQL Server. Since the paths the Wizard is presenting to you are not available on your machine it seems like your copying this database over to a remote server, not your local machine. To access the files you would need to follow the answer David Browne posted.

Here is more documentation on the [database detach and attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-detach-and-attach-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) method.